# how to pass values to paremeters of a module when it is a built-in?

Tags: linux-device-driver

How to pass / set values to paremeters of a module when it is a built-in in linux?   Hor example, consider the usb gadget g_mass-storage module.  When it is compiled as a module (.ko) we can append the file name to the module as:

```
modprobe g_file_storage  file=/abc/xyz
```

How to feed file info when it is compiled as a built-in??

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out on [Siach blog](http://baruch.siach.name/blog/posts/linux_kernel_module_parameters/), answer is in Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt:

Module parameters for modules that are built into the kernel image are specified on the kernel command line with the module name plus `.` plus parameter name, with `=` and `<value>` if appropriate, such as:

```
usbcore.blinkenlights=1
```

These are usually referred to as `bootargs` and can be set in the boot-loader that loads the Linux kernel (**u-boot**, **grub** etc.).